# Polymorphism not understanding

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have two classes derived from the same base class

```
public class AugInfo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Boolean LockedOut { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int ModelsCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }

    public AugInfo() { }
```

}

```
public class AdminUserInfo : AugInfo
public class GroupUserInfo : AugInfo
```

And two functions described bellow

```
    protected List<AdminUserInfo> FilterUsers(List<AdminUserInfo> users,SearchViewModel<AdminUserInfo, EnumUserSort> search)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(d => 
             d.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())
                  || d.Name.ToString().Contains(search.SearchString) ||
                  d.Company.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return users;
    }


 protected List<GroupUserInfo> FilterUsers(List<GroupUserInfo> users,SearchViewModel<GroupUserInfo, EnumUserSort> search)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(d => d.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())
              || d.Name.ToString().Contains(search.SearchString) ||
              d.Company.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

In this functions I use only those properties which belong to `AugInfo`.
I wander is there a way to combine them into one function using `Polymorphism` or `Generic types`. I couldn't do that.

I've tried to declare a function something like this

```
    protected List<AugInfo> FilterUsers(List<AugInfo> users,SearchViewModel<AugInfo, EnumUserSort> search)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(d => d.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())
                  || d.Name.ToString().Contains(search.SearchString) ||
                  d.Company.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

But unfortunately I can't call that function

```
 List<AdminUserInfo> users= FilterUsers(users, search);
```

I get conver error

Comment: Why couldn't you do that?  What did you try?  What happened when you tried?  Why didn't those solutions work?

Comment: Give me a minute to edit my post and add what I've tried to do.

Comment: Hint: Your parameters to FilterUsers() use discrete classes although that's not necessary at all here. Try IEnumerable<AugInfo> for the list instead.

Comment: Why shouldn't this possible ?

Comment: You specifically said that you think you need to use generics to solve the problem.  So how did you attempt to do that?  What generic method did you write, and how did it not solve your problem?

Comment: I've written exactly the same function as it is described in JasperMoneyshot's answer, but the problem is that `d.Email` is not recognized because the compiler don't know anything about the type of `T`.

Comment: PMF when I try to call `List<AdminUserInfo> users= FilterUsers(users, search);` using `IEnumerable<AugInfo>` it says I have convertation error.

Comment: as @HimBromBeere correctly pointed out you need a type constraint on T, so it should look like: protected List<T> FilterUsers<T>(List<T> users, SearchViewModel<T, EnumUserSort> search) where T: AugInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics should be used here:

```
protected List<T> FilterUsers<T>(List<T> users, SearchViewModel<T, EnumUserSort> search) where T : AugInfo {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchString)) {
        users = users.Where(d =>
         d.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())
              || d.Name.ToString().Contains(search.SearchString) ||
              d.Company.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
    return users;
}
```

Just writing `List<AugInfo>` is not enough here because `List<T>` is not contravariant and covariant at the same time (such thing does not exist in C#). You can't convert `List<BaseType>` to `List<DerivedType>`.

Answer (score 2):

You need egeneric constraint on `T` so that only types deriving from `AugInfo` can be used as generic argument:

```
protected List<T> FilterUsers<T>(List<T> users, SearchViewModel<T, EnumUserSort> search) where T: AugInfo
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.SearchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(d => 
            d.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())
                || d.Name.ToString().Contains(search.SearchString) 
                || d.Company.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
    return users;
}
```

Comment: It was what I wanted, But now I have an error `imported type AugInfo is invalid. It contains a circular base class dependency`. What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: @KarenAvdalyan Obviously that your project references another one which references the first one. However that goes far beyond the scope of this question as it is, as you didn´t say anything about the assemblies where those types are defined.